# Deploy react redux starter kit on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, npm, babeljs

I downloaded the [starter kit for react and redux](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). It's really nice and works fine in localhost with the command `npm run dev` but I'm not able to deploy it on the server.

First, I use the command `npm run deploy` which clean and compile my `src` folder in the `dist` folder. Then, I deploy the server on Heroku. Once all is built, the server run `npm start` which execute the command `babel-node bin/server`. This command is not recognized by the heroku server.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to debug this. I tried to clone again the repo, then :

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run deploy`
3. Publish on Heroku and I have the same error without changing anything on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work on heroku is because there isn't any production server ready in this project for your deployment as specified here : https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit#deployment

When you run the `npm run deploy` command, all the front-end code is compiled in the `/dist` folder.

In order to deploy it on heroku you need to :

- Create a very simple http server always serving the file index.html. Here is the main part using Express or Koa

  `app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
  });`
- Modifying the `npm start` script in order to target this new production ready server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that soon and I'll validate your answer. Thanks